# Is Geoserver mandatory for developing GIS web application in Java using Ol4JSF in NetBeans IDE?

Tags: geoserver, java, open-source-gis, openlayers-2, web-gis

I am developing a GIS web application which involves querying and creating map layers dynamically (like page getting refreshed for every 5 minutes) and also static querying etc... This application interacts with PostgreSQL for non-spatial data rendering.. I am using NetBeans to develop the application. Is it mandatory to use Geoserver in the project? FYI, I am planning to use OL4JSF with Jsp to render the maps in browser where user interactions will be carried out.

If Geoserver is mandatory, let me know why?

Comment: Not only is it not mandatory, it is not the only geo-data serving solution (e.g. QGIS Server, ArcSDE, MapServer etc).

Comment: Thank you for the info MappaGnosis :) Yes I am aware, but I am confused with configuring all these into one application.

Answer (score 2):

Geoserver is not mandatory. If you need a WFS or WMS or WMTS or WPS or CSW or WCS server for your application needs, it is an option, but there are other options for all of those, in open source and proprietary forms. If you are looking for open source options, many are listed at [OSGeo](http://www.osgeo.org) - see the project links under Web Mapping and Metadata Catalog headings.

Use what you need. Don't use what you don't.

If you have a more specific question about how to do something in particular, feel free to ask that, as another question.

Comment: Thank you @BradHards. Yup I have questions, I will post a new one then. Can you please lemme know about those other options in opensource?

Comment: I'll add a reference, but a google search would also be an option.

Comment: Yeah! I got to know about Mapserver, QGIS Server as open sources as mentioned by MappaGnosis in a reply to my above question. Yes I am aware of those. This is where I am confused, I have to use any of these  servers (opensource only) compulsorily in my application for WCS,WMS etc... services? Then may I know what this ol4jsf for? I am half-baked in programming. Please help.

Comment: I have posted a new question in this link http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157398/what-is-the-best-possible-configuration-for-opensource-gis-web-application-to-ge. Lemme know you can help.